# Determining the probability of $X_2 \ge X_1$ given they have different probability functions

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, density-function

Suppose that I have a random variable $X_1$ which is normally distributed, and a random variable $X_2$ having the density function shown in the figure below. How would I determine ${\rm P}(X_1 \le X_2)$?

[image]

Comment: In the absence of any information about the _joint_ distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$, you can make the answer work out to be almost anything you like.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you. Yes, since they are independent there isn't any information on their _Joint Distribution_. I was thinking of just subtracting the Area associated with ${\rm P}(X_2)$ from that associated with ${\rm P}(X_1 \le X_2)$. I know that you said I could do anything, but does this sound reasonable enough?

Comment: If they are independent, you know their joint distribution if you know their marginal distributions. $P(X_1\leq t, X_2\leq s)=P(X_1 \leq t)P(X_2 \leq s)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ have joint density $f_{X_1, X_2}$ and marginal densities $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$, we have
$$
P(X_1 \leq X_2)
  = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x_2} f_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) dx_1 dx_2 .
$$
If the two random variables are independent, the probability is
\begin{align*}
P(X_1 \leq X_2)
  & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{x_2} f_{X_1}(x_1) f_{X_2}(x_2) dx_1 dx_2\\
  & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_2}(x_2) \left\{\int_{-\infty}^{x_2} f_{X_1}(x_1)
dx_1\right\} dx_2 \\
  & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X_2}(x_2) F_{X_1}(x_2) dx_2 \\
  & = E\left\{ F_{X_1}(X_2) \right\}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we have $P(X_2 \leq X_1) = E\left\{ F_{X_2}(X_1) \right\}$, and hence
$$
P(X_1 \leq X_2) = E\left\{ F_{X_1}(X_2) \right\} = 1 - E\left\{ F_{X_2}(X_1) \right\}.
$$
Note that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution, then
$U = F_{X_1}(X_2) = F_{X_2}(X_2)$ follows a uniform $U(0, 1)$ distribution, and
hence $P(X_1 \leq X_2) = E(U) = 0.5$ as one would expect.

Now, based on your graphic and the information provided in one of your comments, it seems that a shifted exponential distribution would be a reasonable choice for the distribution of $X_2$.
So, if $X_1 \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $X_2$ follows a shifted exponential distribution with rate $\lambda > 0$ and location parameter $a$, that is $F_{X_2}(x) = 1 - \exp\{-\lambda(x-a)\}$ if $x > a$ and $F_{X_2}(x) = 0 $ otherwise, then the probability is
\begin{align}
P(X_1 \leq X_2)
 &= 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_{X_2}(x) f_{X_1}(x) dx \\
 &= 1 - \int_{a}^{\infty} [ 1 - \exp\{-\lambda(x-a)\} ] f_{X_1}(x) dx \\
 &= 1 - P(X_1 > a) + \int_{a}^{\infty} \exp\{-\lambda(x-a)\} f_{X_1}(x) dx \\
 &= \Phi\left( \frac{a - \mu}{\sigma} \right)
      + \exp \left\{ \lambda (a - \mu) + \frac{\lambda^2\sigma^2}{2} \right\}
        \Phi\left( \frac{\mu - a - \lambda \sigma^2}{\sigma} \right),
\end{align}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ denotes the standard normal distribution function.

In your case, numerical values of the parameters could be $a = 2$ and $\lambda = 1$ (assuming that $X_2$ corresponds to "Strain" $\times 1000$).

Comment: @Quantlbex Thanks. I have literally manufactured the graph in the question by using the equation y=(4.754/78504)*exp(-779.4*x), where each value on the X-Axis is directly associated with a probability. I am therefore unsure what the PDF or CDF would be, or if it even has one. Also, may I ask why you don't believe the answer suggested below won't work?

Comment: What makes you think that I believe that another answer won't work?

Comment: The function you manifactured is unlikely to be a PDF; it doesn't seem to integrate to 1. The [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Probability_density_function) with an appropriate rate parameter might suit your needs.

Comment: @Quantlbex I just assumed that, as you've provided another answer. So, I guess it does work then? Anyway, would you know how I would go about implementing your answer given the statement I made above your question? Thanks.

Comment: @Quantlbex I have taken you suggestion and am now looking at the exponential Distribution. Would you know how I could possibly make the CDF of my Exponential Distribution give the same plot as the graph in the original question. I tried equating the equation associated with the CDF of an Exponential Distribution to that associated with this graph in order to get the decay rate. However, this didn't work.

Comment: What is the mean of $X_2$? And its smallest possible value?

Comment: The problem is actually determining the mean for $X_2$ given the information in the last comment. Is it possible to just equate the polynomial equation I have for my graph with that of the CDF of an Exponential Distribution?

Comment: No, I don't see how it would be possible. What information do you have about "Strain"? Is the smallest possible value 2e-3 as the graph suggests? Is the average value of "Strain" 3e-3?

Comment: @Quantlbex Actually yes. The lowest Strain value is 2e-3 and the highest is 8e-3 and 5e-3 is associated with a y value of 0.1

Comment: Are these information based on a sample of observations, meaning that there could be values of Strain smaller that 2e-3 or larger than 8e-3 but they were just not observed, or are these bounds really hard bounds that could never be "breached"?

Comment: @Quantlbex These are basically hard bounds, that have been set.

Comment: Ok, I see. I've added in my answer the solution for the case where $X_2$ follows a shifted exponential distribution. If you need to have a hard upper bound then you might want to use a truncated version of this exponential distribution.

Comment: @Quantlbex Thanks. I was just wondering how you determine $a$ to be 0.002 and $\lambda = 1$? Also, when you say _truncated_ version of the distribution, would it just be possible to scale it so that it satisfies this upper bound?

Comment: You probably need to change some $\lambda$'s in arguments of exponential functions to $-\lambda$. Otherwise your CDFs diverge (instead of asymptotically approaching 1 from below) as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Parameter $a$ corresponds to the lower bound of the support of $X_2$, and $\lambda$ to the limit of $f_{X_2}$ as $X_2 \to a$. No, the exponential distribution doesn't have an upper bound, so scaling it wouldn't change the problem, hence the need for truncation.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate, yes, thanks for spotting these typos.

Comment: Note that with $a = 2$ and $\lambda = 1$, $P(X_2 > 8) \approx 0.0025$, which is rather small. I'll let you determine if putting a probability of $0.0025$ (instead of $0$) on values larger that $8$ is a problem in your application.

Comment: +1 good post. OP: Note that if the parameters are estimated from data, the calculation of the probability is conditional on the estimates being the same as the population values. A possibly more useful answer would take into account the fact that you don't know the values, only their estimates. This may not make much difference in large samples, but might make a more substantive difference in smaller samples. Not also that if you have data, you have a nonparametric estimate of the probability - the sample proportion of times that $x_{1i}\leq x_{2j}$ (across all $i,j$ pairs)

Comment: @QuantIbex This equation is very useful. I am just having an issue with the term $ \Phi\left( \frac{\mu - a}{\sigma} \right) $, where a = 0, as my $\mu = 0.003$ and  $\sigma = 0.00075$, I get that the aforementioned term will always be 1 and therefore end up having ${\rm P}(X_1  \leq X_2 )$ is negative. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry to involve you this question again, but I was hoping you could tell where I'm going wrong, based on the comment above this.

Comment: I've corrected the typos I found when re-doing the computations to get the final expression. Feel free to do the computations yourself to double check.

Answer (score 2):

If your graph above represents a probability density, then you can find the density for $X_2 - X_1$ via the convolution integral. Then $P(X_2 <= X_1)$ is equivalent to the probability that $P(X_2 - X_1 <= 0)$, using the density function derived from convolution. If you have discrete distributions, then there's an equivalent process using a sum instead of an integral.

For the analytic approach, see if this helps: http://courses.washington.edu/bioen316/Assignments/316_SCP.pdf

If you can sample from both, then simulations of $X_2 - X_1$ will give a working approximation. I'm only familiar with how to do that with an inverse CDF, but there's a computational method mentioned here that may interest you: http://blog.quantitations.com/tutorial/2012/11/20/sampling-from-an-arbitrary-density/

Answer (score 1):

The difference between two independent variables has a distribution given by the convolution of the two individual distributions. So basically just smooth that curve above with the normal distribution. It will extend into the negative region and have a smooth peak somewhere in the positive region. That's about all there is to say about it.

Comment: Thanks. May I know why you say the difference between the two independent variables is given by the convolution of the two distribution? Also, when you say smooth the curve with the Normal Distribtuion, do you effectively mean just joining the two curves together?

Comment: Well, here is source on it.http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf

Comment: If you wanted to prove it, you can just do a transformation from X, Y to Z=X+Y and W=X-Y which will be independent if X and Y are. Then just integrate over Z. That leaves P(W) as a convolution.

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you mean now. I get the following expression: $\int_{0}^{z} (lambda*e^{-lambda(k-z)}*e^{-(k^2/2)})/sqrt(2*pi)dk$

Comment: The integral should go 0 to infinity and so you can write it as an Error function.

Comment: Sorry, but the assertion "difference between two independent variables has a distribution given by the convolution of the two individual distributions" is not quite right; it is the cross-correlation (in the sense that time-series people and signal processing people use it). The assertion that $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent if $X$ and $Y$ are independent is false too except when $X$ and $Y$ are **jointly normal** which does not hold here.

Comment: You are right about the independence being incorrect. They are however uncorrelated but only if <x^2> = <y^2>, for example, they are from the same distribution. I'm not sure why I said that since I don't believe it was required for this problem.

Comment: You are also right about it being correlation for differences and convolution for sums. Often it is the same (up to a shift anyway) when one or both of the distributions are symmetric like here. By up to shift, I mean that mean <X-Y> = <X> - <Y> and <X+Y> = <X> + <Y> so they have different means but same distribution about the mean when one is symmetric.

Comment: Here is another useful source http://www.cs.unm.edu/~williams/cs530/sum.pdf