# Obtaining a Probability Distribution From a Survival Function

Tags: survival, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

**Edit**: I basically want to have a probability curve where a X value of 0.002 would be associated with a Probability of 1 and would also have data points of (0.005,0.1), (0.008,0) which is seen in the graph below. However, I then realised I would need to check the probability that the aforementioned random variable is greater than another random variable, which is normally distributed, and for that I would need both to be distributions. So, is there some way I could create a PDF having a CDF like the graph below? I realise the CDF must always be increasing, so would it be possible to have a graph increasing with the x values increasing from 0.008 to 0.002? 
**Edit**:
[image]

Comment: A CDF is increasing; it's graph can never look like that for any distribution. Do you mean that the graph should match that of a PDF?

Comment: @KarlOskar Thanks. I basically wanted to have a graph where a X value of 0.002 would be associated with a Probability of 1 and would also have data points of (0.005,0.1), (0.008,0). However, I then realised I would need to check the [Probability that the random variable here is greater than another random variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90968/determining-the-probability-of-x-2-ge-x-1-given-they-have-different-probabili/90973?noredirect=1#comment178061_90973), which is Normally Distributed and for that I would need both to be distributions.

Comment: @KarlOskar Do you think there is another way of going about this? Or is it possible to draw the CDF going from x values of 0.008 to 0.002?

Comment: Given you haven't drawn a cdf, please clarify your question so as not to be self-contradictory.

Comment: @Glen_b Unfortunately, it seems like it is impossible to get what I want, which is a probability distribution having data points (0.002,1),(0.005,0.1),(0.008,0) where the Y values refer to the probability associated with the X value. This is just a theoretical graph that I have in mind that I am now looking to convert to a probability distribution.

Comment: "Distribution" strictly means 'cdf', but you clearly mean something else. Sometimes people say 'distribution' when they mean density, but I doubt that can be the case (you might know the relative density, but how can you assert the density is 1 at 0.002? It looks like you may mean survivor function. When you say "distribution" do you mean density, or (as it seems), survivor function? (neither of which is a distribution!) In fact, there are an infinite number of densities or survivor functions that take those values... What are the restrictions on this function (whichever one of the two it is)?

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry for the ambiguity. Yes, it is a Survival function. And the only restrictions are that the function has the data points (0.002,1),(0.005,0.1),(0.008,0).

Comment: please edit your question, which is currently talking about the cdf when it means something else.

Comment: @Glen_b Actually, I still need the CDF of some distribution to look like the survival curve in the question. However, I realise this is impossible, so I think I will delete this question. But, before that, I just want to know, do you think it will be possible to determine the ${\rm P}(X_1 \le X_2)$ given that $X_1$ is a Normally distributed random variable and $X_2$ is the survival function as shown above.

Comment: Don't delete your question - you're nearly at the point of asking the right one (actually, it has an answer, so you won't be able to in any case). Your statement in that first sentence of your last comment makes no sense; it seems to conflate survivor functions and cdfs (which makes me think you perhaps don't know what a cdf *is*). I can generate any number of distributions whose survival function has the characteristics you describe - relatively easily. [The survivor function is simply 1-F, where F is the cdf.]

Comment: @Glen_b I see the relationship between the survival function and the cdf now. I have the survival function $y = (4.754*exp{(-779.4 *x))}*(1/78504)$. So, I could get the CDF of each value of x purely by doing $1-y$? Also, would this be the CDF for an Exponential Distribution? Thanks.

Comment: That function doesn't look *quite* right. How did you get the values?

Comment: @Glen_b I just used the `fit` function in Matlab and put in my data points of (0.002,1),(0.005,0.1),(0.008,0)

Comment: Two things: (1) did you compute the fitted values of that function? (I did!) You might be surprised what you ended up with, which plainly isn't an exponential survivor function - at least not one that starts at 0.002. $\,\,$ (2) If you want to guarantee your "known" value at $x=.002$ and fit the other two (being data), they shouldn't be treated as if they were all equally precise data.

Comment: Okay, three things... (3) the two actual values you have shouldn't be equally precise either, since the value you give at .008 is also a lower bound for the function ... it can't go lower.

Comment: @Glen_b very sorry about that. I think the actual function is this $y=(4.754∗exp(−779.4∗x))$ . I've edited the Original question to show the graph for this equation. And the data I am now using is (0.002,1),(0.005,0.1),(0.007,0.01),(0.008,0.01). Is it alright that these are precise?

Comment: The point was that the variability in actual cdf values (or their complement) that are very close to 1 or 0 would be less than values near 0.5 (or really, anywhere not so close to the bounds), because the ones near the bounds cannot move beyond the bounds. It doesn't so much matter because the fit was pretty good before. The new value would perhaps be better used as an out of sample check first to make sure things are behaving as they should. Why is y(.007)=y(.008) now?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I've just realised that I have been going about this the wrong way. The best way for me to deal with this would be to look at a discrete Distribution such as the Poisson Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $X=1000\times$"Strain", you might want to consider a shifted [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with rate $\lambda = 1$ and location parameter $a = 2$ having cumulative distribution function $F(x) = 1 - \exp\{-\lambda(x-a)\}$ if $x > a$ and $F(x) = 0 $ otherwise. The corresponding PDF and CDF are shown below. Note that $f(5) \approx 0.049$ and $f(8) \approx 0.0025$.
[image: PDF]
[image: CDF]