# Probability equation is > real positive number

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

(I have finally edited my question)

I have one equation being compared to a number:

X = any positive real number

X'= (L)+2(Y)+3(Z)

The value of L, Y, and Z are always between 0-1 and its value can change, but it has a probability associated with it. If I use actual numbers, imagine:

L=  0.0-0.3 (90% of the time),
 0.0-0.5 (60% of the time),
 0.0-0.9 (10% of the time)

Y=  0 or 1 (Y=1, 1% of the time and Y=0, 99% of the time)

Z=
0.00-0.25, 25% of the time
0.25-0.50, 25% of the time
0.50-0.75, 25% of the time
0.75-1.00, 25% of the time

X=2.50

L, Y, Z are independent variables.

I am curious as to how I could calculate the probability of X'>X. Is there a model/equation I can use that can calculate such a thing for me?

Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: Are L,Y, and Z independent? Also, I think you're going to need more information because depending on the distributions of L,Y, and Z the probability will be different.

Comment: Yes, L, Y, and Z are independent. L,Y and Z follow a normal distribution

Comment: Have you made an attempt on this problem? If the three are independent then you can split their join probabilities. Again the problem is not well specified. A normal distribution is continuous so no single number occurs with probability greater than zero. Are you sure you don't mean that 50% of the time L is below .6?

Comment: My most sincere apologies, I do indeed mean that 50% of the time L is indeed below 0.6.

Comment: No worries! You'll need to switch those inequalities in the post, but now the problem makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks - done! I hope this makes the problem much easier to understand and relatively easily to solve. My frustration lies with the fact that I don't have a model to follow to solve the problem.

Comment: I think we'll also need to know the standard deviation for those distributions. Are you sure that all 3 are not "standard normal"?

Comment: You raise a great question. Your questions got me thinking and have helped me consider another potential model which includes a binomial distribution Considering I am a newbie to posting (I've mainly been lurking - is it within my rights to delete this post and post another question? Adding much more valuable information to the initial question just as SD, type of distribution and allowing me to correct my earlier error?

Comment: So there isn't really a mystery here to solve this if you know L,Y, and Z. You don't need a `model' to solve, you just need to find the joint distribution.

Comment: If L, Y, and Z were Normally distributed, they would not always be between 0-1.  Instead of deleting this and posting a new question, revise this question.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. If you edit your question to clarify what you mean, it isn't necessary to create a second post, and it will populate the reopen queue for a re-open vote. The SO model encourages users to edit problematic posts rather than spam the forums

Comment: You need to fix specification for $L$. Presuming there are 3 intervals for the fixed-up $L$, there are $24 = 4 * 2 * 3$ different combinations of interval values for $X'$. The probability of each combination is the product of the probabilities of each, which will be P(chosen L interval)(0.5)(0.25). The value of $X'$ will be the range of possible results with those intervals. E.g..if the first intervals are chosen, then $X '= [0,0.3] + 2*0 + 3[0,0.25] = [0,1.05]$.  With the computed probability, $X'$ has a value somewhere in the interval $[0,1]$. Do this for all combinations. Make conclusions.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. This makes a lot of sense. However, is there some sort of equation that can calculate this for me, instead of going for a trial and error type of approach? If the problem gets more complicated, and the number of combinations increases to 100+, this approach might be cumbersome considering I plan on adding a couple more variables to my equation.

Comment: Half of the answer (the comparison) is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90968.  The other half, involving computing the sum of random variables, is illustrated in hundreds of threads.  Here's a focused site search that turns up many of them: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=distribution+sum+convolution.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, whuber. Math and statistics have always been a passion of mine albeit medicine being my current practicing field. Thank you for leading me in the right direction! (PS: Is it normal the post is closed!?)

Comment: My comment is predicated on your not having any further information as to the distribution within each interval. Hence my treatment using interval arithmetic http://www.cs.utep.edu/interval-comp/ , which can be automated. II you can specify the distribution within each interval, for instance, uniform, then you can do traditional probability calculations per the links from @whuber nstead of interval arithmetic calculations. The interval approach will have messy conclusions.

Comment: Correction of typo in my comment 2 of mine back.  $[0,1]$ in 3rd to last sentence should be $[0,1.05]$